# Modifying the $ positional operator

Tags: arrays, mongodb, matching, positional-operator

I'm following [the example in the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator):

```
> t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4b97e62bf1d8c7152c9ccb74"), "title" : "ABC",
  "comments" : [ { "by" : "joe", "votes" : 3 }, { "by" : "jane", "votes" : 7 } ] }

> t.update( {'comments.by':'joe'}, {$inc:{'comments.$.votes':1}}, false, true )

> t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4b97e62bf1d8c7152c9ccb74"), "title" : "ABC",
  "comments" : [ { "by" : "joe", "votes" : 4 }, { "by" : "jane", "votes" : 7 } ] }
```

This shows how you can search for Joe's votes count and increment it. What I'd like to accomplish is incrementing Jane's votes count when querying for Joe's. In my case, `comments` is an array always of length 2. Perhaps it's best showed with my current (non-working) syntax:

```
t.update( {'comments.by':'joe'}, {$inc:{'comments[1-$].votes':1}}, false, true )
```

I thought `$` would be `0` here because Joe is first in the array. To get the other array index, I assumed `1-$` would do the job, but it doesn't.

How can one match the other array element than the one queried for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `$` points to first matched element in the array. You can't build references to other elements that are relative to that matched element. You can always use absolute references, though (`comments.1.votes`).

Comment: Hmm, mongo has a lot of restrictions, but perhaps I'm not using it correctly. What I'd like to achieve doesn't sound too complicated. Is there any way to do such a thing in mongo?

Comment: I guess, your data is not about posts and comments, right? What are you trying to achieve? There must be more idiomatic way.

Comment: True :) Basically I'm trying to create a trivial "hello world" chat application, where posting a chat message would increment the `unreadMessages` count of the *other* chat user. I'm querying for the chat room id and the *current* user id (so that nobody else can update that room), but with the `$` operator I can only increment the `unreadMessages` of the current user, which isn't meaningful.

Comment: I'd send several separate updates. An alternative is to fetch the whole document first, calculate new array (with updates values) and send it. But this is not atomic. Try the first one, it should work great.

Comment: Yet another alternative is to rethink your schema and convert that array of hashes to a nested hash structure. Then you'll reference users by names instead of indexes, and it should be possible to update several users at once.